# Как присвоить javascript - переменной цену выбранного товара Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php

**Добрый день.**

Прошу о помощи!

Вот тестовая страница

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пункт 1 - "Выбрать из наших образцов" кликабельный, там во всплывающем окне каталог вариативных товаров с выбором вариации, кнопка Добавить в корзину и всплыв/окно закрывается.

В пункте 2 - "Выбрать оснастку" - то же самое, но там будет  каталог простых товаров. Будет только кнопка Добавить в корзину и тоже будет просто закрываться попап.

**Проблема вот в чем** - как javascript-переменной "osnastka"  присвоить цену выбранной вариации товара в пункте №1, а переменной  "klishe" присвоить цену простого товара, выбранного в пункте №2 ?

Цель этих действий - требуется вывести на этой странице цены выбранных товаров, и подставить в калькулятор, чтобы справа после выбора способа доставки отобразить общую цену товара. Этот пункт я знаю как делать, но я не могу получить цены двух выбранных товаров в текущей сессии и присвоить их переменным javascript.

**Не получается в переменную osnastka присвоить цену выбранной вариации товара из пункта №1, а в переменную klishe присвоить цену простого товара из пункта №2**

```js
// калькулятор

var osnastka = 0,
  klishe = 0,
  shipp = 0;

$("#klishe").change(function() {
  klishe = $('#klishe').val();
  summ();
});

$("#osnastka").change(function() {
  osnastka = $('#osnastka').val();
  summ();
});

$("#shipp").change(function() {
  shipp = $('#shipp').val();
  summ();
});


function summ() {
  klishe = Number(klishe);
  osnastka = Number(osnastka);
  shipp = Number(shipp);

  $("#summ").text(osnastka + klishe + shipp + ' руб.');
};
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_id">
   <select name="shipp" id="shipp">
    <option value="">Способ доставки </option>
    <option value="0">самовывоз </option>
    <option value="300">доставка курьером по городу на след день </option>
    <option value="700">срочная доставка </option>
   </select>
   
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="guarantee">
  <div class="guarantee_id">Итого: <div id="summ">0 руб</div></div>
 </div>
```

Это весь код калькулятора. Может, надо добавить в форму калькулятора 2 таких же select с , и в value простого товара вывести get_price_html(); ?>, а для вариативного id вариации?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Большое спасибо всем, кто ответит.**

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Если в value вывожу get_price_html(); ?>, ломается страница. Вот текст ошибки -

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on null in /home/...

**Важное уточнение:** все работы проводятся на странице, созданной из админки, и код я ввожу через редактор админки (ибо php-файла нет).

---

### ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2

Повторил это на странице товара - попробовал через редактор админки просто вывести цену данного товара -- та же ошибка.
Другие команды php вывожу таким же способом через редактор - и все работает.

### Обновление 3

Вставил этот код для эксперимента стандартно, в файл single-product.php, выдало уже такую ошибку (на странице товара) -

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on null in /home/.../single-product.php on line 54

**Что с этой функцией function get_price_html()  не так?**

---

### Обновление 4, наверное последнее.

Погуглил. Вставил функцию в function.php

```html
function add_price_widget()
{
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    $thePrice = $product->get_price(); //will give raw price
    echo $thePrice;
    }
```

На странице товара add_price_widget() прекрасно работает и выводит цену и в произвольном месте, и в value,

а на этой моей странице, которая на скрине вверху, где товары еще не выбраны и функция не имеет значений переменных, снова ошибка, пробовал и в пустом месте страницы, и в value - без разницы, ошибка -

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on boolean in /var/www/.../twentysixteen/functions.php:611

Строка 611 - $thePrice = $product->get_price();

Comment: А что именно у вас не работает? Вот ваш код: https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/QWWJjed?editors=1111
Сумма складывается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!   Не получается в переменную osnastka присвоить цену выбранной вариации товара из пункта №1, а в переменную klishe присвоить цену простого товара из пункта №2

Comment: А можете добавить полный пример с html, чтоб можно было понять где вы видите что в переменных нет данных ?

Comment: В этих двух переменных нет данных, потому что их там не может быть - я ничего им не присваивал, кроме 0. Калькулятор показывает только value из shipp = $('#shipp').val();  Сейчас покажу

Comment: Это весь код калькулятора. Может, надо добавить в форму калькулятора 2 таких же  select   с  <option value=""></option>, и в value простого товара  вывести <?рhp  echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>, а для вариативного id вариации?

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то такое хотели сделать?

```js
var osnastka = 0,
  klishe = 0,
  shipp = 0;

$("#klishe").change(function() {
  klishe = $('#klishe').val();
  $('#klishe-price').text("Клише: " + klishe + " руб")
  summ();
});

$("#osnastka").change(function() {
  osnastka = $('#osnastka').val();
  $('#osnastka-price').text("Остнаска: " + osnastka + " руб")
  summ();
});

$("#shipp").change(function() {
  shipp = $('#shipp').val();
  summ();
});


function summ() {
  klishe = Number(klishe);
  osnastka = Number(osnastka);
  shipp = Number(shipp);

  $("#summ").text(osnastka + klishe + shipp + ' руб.');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <select name="osnastka" id="osnastka">
    <option value="0">Выберите вариант</option>
    <option value="10">Оснастка 1 </option>
    <option value="20">Оснастка 2 </option>
    <option value="30">Оснастка 3 </option>
  </select>
  <select name="klishe" id="klishe">
    <option value="0">Выберите вариант</option>
    <option value="40">Клише 1 </option>
    <option value="50">Клише 2 </option>
    <option value="60">Клише 3 </option>
    
  </select>
  <div class="block_id">
   <select name="shipp" id="shipp">
    <option value="">Способ доставки </option>
    <option value="0">самовывоз </option>
    <option value="300">доставка курьером по городу на след день </option>
    <option value="700">срочная доставка </option>
   </select>
   
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="guarantee">
    <div id="osnastka-price">Остнаска: 0 руб</div>
    <div id="klishe-price">Клише: 0 руб</div>
  <div class="guarantee_id">Итого: <div id="summ">0 руб</div></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Да, именно!   Теперь надо в value простого товара вывести <?рhp echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>, а для вариативного id вариации?

Comment: Все верно, в value цену товара.

Comment: Пробую! Огромное спасибо.

Comment: Если в value вывожу <?рhp echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>, ломается страница...

Comment: Выше в вопрос вставил текст ошибки.

Comment: Повторил это на странице товара - попробовал через редактор админки просто вывести цену данного товара -- та же ошибка.
Другие команды php вывожу таким же способом через редактор - и все работает

Comment: Вставил этот код для эксперимента стандартно, в файл single-product.php, выдало уже такую ошибку (на странице товара) - 

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on null in /home/nadosajt/vb.in.ua/seal/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/woocommerce/owp-single-product.php on line 54. Что с этой функцией не так?

Answer (score 0):

$('#klishe').val() примет данные только в том случае, если $('#klishe') это элемент формы (input), если нет, то $('#klishe').text();

Если $('#osnastka') это select, то – $('#osnastka option:selected').val();

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, попробую!

Answer (score 0):

Погуглил. Вставил функцию в function.php

```html
function add_price_widget()
{
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    $thePrice = $product->get_price(); //will give raw price
    echo $thePrice;
    }
```

На странице товара add_price_widget() прекрасно работает и выводит цену и в произвольном месте, и в value, а на моей странице, где товары еще не выбраны и функция не имеет значений переменных, снова ошибка, пробовал и в пустом месте страницы, и в value - без разницы, ошибка -

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on boolean in /var/www/.../twentysixteen/functions.php:611

Строка 611 - $thePrice = $product->get_price();